# How to change redirect url on soundcloud?

Tags: soundcloud

I want to know how i can change my app' redirect url on soundcloud please.
I have been using the api for just 3 months so i'm not very familiar with all this...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to get in touch with SoundCloud Support to have this changed: support@soundcloud.com.

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud seems to be still be working on changes to their API.

> With the new registration it is currently not possible to edit your redirect URI. This is for security reasons around the authentication connect flow. That said, we are hoping to change the form to include both a development and production URI if needed. For now, if you let us know what you need it changed to and confirm which application you are needing this changed on, we can make this change for you.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/api-sign-up-changes